# I am facing following issue during installation of .IPA files on my Mac m1

Tags: macos

I have recently purchased Mac,when I was trying to install Instagram using iMazing and while exporting.ipa file it is showing following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga4eS.png)

Answer (score -1):

This was a problem with iMazing 2.13.6.  It was fixed—all you need to do is upgrade to Version 2.13.7.